# CQ5 list component

Tags: aem

I need to extend OOTB cq5 list component for sorting the pages. Can anyone please help me tell me how this list component performs sorting?

Answer (score 2):

The sorting is done using the `PageComparator` class defined in List.java (`/libs/foundation/src/impl/src/main/java/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/List.java`).

The following is the snippet of code from the PageComparator.

```
public int compare(P p1, P p2) {
    int comp = getKey(p1).compareTo(getKey(p2));
    return (comp != 0 && isDateProperty) ? -comp : comp;
}

private String getKey(P p) {
    return p.getProperties().get(property, "");
}
```